# Заменить ответ Controller на новый

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-8

создаю проект на:

- c# asp net core
- net8.0 (stable)

В проекте, использую `Controllers` исключительно для `api` части.

Хотелось, чтобы ответы представляли собой целую единую систему.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно заменять ответы контроллеров?

К примеру:

```cs
[ApiController]
[ApiVersion("1.0")]
[Route("api/v{version:ApiVersion}/[controller]/[action]")
public class CustomController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<CustomAnswerModel> GetAnswer()
    {
        return await _database....;
    }
}
```

В ответе получим класс `CustomAnswerModel`.

Пример ответа:

```json
{
    "key_1": "value_1",
    "key_2": "value_2",
    ...
}
```

Однако, хотелось бы, чтобы ответ был примерно такой:

```json
{
    "success": {
        "key_1": "value_1",
        "key_2": "value_2",
        ...
    }
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно заменить существующий ответ на новый?

Comment: нужно использовать [фильтры](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-8.0)

Comment: Для такого используют **Result Filters**

Answer (score 2):

Почти в любом из [типов фильтров](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-8.0#filter-types) можно изменить результат.

Однако если нужно только изменить результат можно воспользоваться [`ResultFilter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-8.0#result-filters)

Например:

```
public class SampleResultFilter : IResultFilter
{
    public void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext context)
    {
        context.Result = new ObjectResult(new {
            success = context.Result
        })
    }
}
```